# How to Shuffle Items in a ListView C#?

Tags: c#, listview, media-player

I am making a very simple MP3, WAV, and WMA media player.

The music files are listed within a listView consisting of two columns (Column 1: Audio Title, Column 2: File Location).

I would like to create a button that will shuffle and randomize ALL of the items that are in the list view.

Here's an example:

```
Title    Location
SONG1    C:\\A LOCATION
SONG2    "
SONG3    "
SONG4    "
SONG5    "
SONG6    "
```

into this:

```
Title    Location
SONG6    C:\\A LOCATION
SONG3    "
SONG4    "
SONG2    "
SONG1    "
SONG5    "
```

I'm using axMediaPlayer (.wmp)

Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomizedList = from item in listbox.Items
                     orderby rnd.Next()
                     select item;
```

Then assign the randomizedList back to the listbox

or

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Usage:

```
var products = listview.Items.ToList();
products.Shuffle();
```

Comment: Only issue is that I'm using a listView, not a listBox... :/

Comment: Please give a better description of the error. What part of the code underlines with an error and what does the error message say.

Comment: Error: "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'ListViewCollection'. 'OrderBy' not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'item'.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    public static void Randomize(this ListView lv)
    {
        ListView.ListViewItemCollection list = lv.Items;
        Random rng = new Random();
        int n = list.Count;
        lv.BeginUpdate();
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            ListViewItem value1 = (ListViewItem)list[k];
            ListViewItem value2 = (ListViewItem)list[n];
            list[k] = new ListViewItem();
            list[n] = new ListViewItem();
            list[k] = value2;
            list[n] = value1;
        }
        lv.EndUpdate();
        lv.Invalidate();
    }
}
```